# Parametric Curves and Equations

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $R_1$, $R_2$ be two parametric curves such that:

- $R_1: z = t + 0\cdot i$ where $0\le t \le 2$
- $R_2: z = n + i n (n-1)$ where $0\le n \le 2$

Let $T_1$, $T_2$ be their images under the mapping $w = i z^2$

1. Find the points $z_1$, $z_2$ at which $R_1$ and $R_2$ intersect and determine the corresponding angles of intersection $a_1$, $a_2$. Sketch $R_1$ and $R_2$.
2. Find the parametric equations for $T_1$ and $T_2$.
3. Find the points $w_1$ and $w_2$ at which $T_1$ and $T_2$ intersect and determine the corresponding angles of intersection $b_1$ and $b_2$. Sketch $T_1$ and $T_2$.

This picture shows the approach I tried which gave me an angle who's tan is undefined.

[image]

Comment: Please indicate what you've already done/tried and what you think about the problem. This lets others give an answer better suited to your background. It also shows that you aren't just trying to get someone to do your homework for you.

Comment: It was easier to take a picture of what I have tried and edit the question, but unfortunately the question was put on hold as an off-topic question.
The main problem I am having now is find out why I am getting an angle who's tan is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle of intersection refers to the angle that the two curves make, but not the argument of the point in the complex plane.

So for example, $z_2=1+0i$, to find $a_2$, you need to know the tangent vector of the curves first.

$R_1:$ $ \frac{dz}{dt}=1$

$R_2$: $\frac{dz}{dn}=1+(2n-1)i$

The angle between the two tangent vectors at $1+0i$ ($t=1$, $n=1$)would be $a_2$, so by either taking dot product, or using $arg(\frac{1+i}{1})$

Comment: Thank you very much Bubububu. This now makes sense. I have edited the question after applying the method you mentioned. And also calculated T1 and T2 by applying the mapping w = iz^2 to both R1 and R2. Does that look reasonable?

Comment: @Josh looks good to me!